# Wait to preform function without freezing the process

Tags: java, time

I want to wait 300ms after 2 lines run to run the same 2 lines again, without freezing the thread.

`wait(300);` and `Thread.sleep(300);`, along with some loop I found on SO (below) either freeze the thread, exit cleanly(?) or lag the thread by running the function a million times.

I want to wait 300 milliseconds and then run

```java
mc.player.rotationPitch = 90;
mc.playerController.processRightClick(mc.player, mc.world, hand);
```

without freezing the thread, as sometimes it doesn't time properly if the thread is frozen, and it's annoying for the user if it's going to freeze every time.

I've tried `wait,` `Thread.sleep`, `TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep` and

```java
                long lastNanoTime = System.nanoTime();
                long nowTime = System.nanoTime();
                while(nowTime/1000000 - lastNanoTime /1000000 < 300 )
                {
                    nowTime = System.nanoTime();
                    System.out.println("KAMI: Tried to pick up bucket");

                }
```

I've already shown the relevant examples above. 
[Full code is here](https://github.com/S-B99/KAMI/blob/temp-features-master/src/main/java/me/zeroeightsix/kami/module/modules/player/NoFall.java)

Expected: thread works normally, and my 2 lines, (rotation pitch and right click) run 300 milliseconds after the previous rotation pitch and right click

Actual results: commented in code. Depending on the method used thread either lags, exits or crashes

Comment: From what you wrote, it seems you are trying to perform tasks that should be run in differents threads into a single one, hence "freezing" the user actions.

Comment: I would prefer to use one thread, as the lines I want to run after it waits is a continuation of the same "action"

Comment: A second thread can be started/stopped/suspended. That's what you need. YOu just need to think how to use it correctly in order to interact smoothly with this action

Comment: Minecraft runs on one "single" thread, it's not possible to use a second thread. That's why the entire program freezes when this one function freezes

Answer (score 0):

You will need another thread to do this "without freezing" the current thread. This can be done quite easily, something like:

```
import java.lang.Thread;

public class Main {

    public static abstract class After extends Thread {

        private int sleep = 0;

        public After(int sleep) {
            this.sleep = sleep;
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(this.sleep);
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                //do something with e
            }
            this.after();
        }

        public abstract void after();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        After after = new After(300) {
            public void after() {
                //mc.player.rotationPitch = 90;
                //mc.playerController.processRightClick(mc.player, mc.world, hand);
                System.out.println("testing");
            }
        };
        after.start(); //this will execute the code in 300 ms

        //do what ever you want to do during the 300ms

        after.join(); //join all threads at the end of your code
        System.out.println("done");
    }
}
```

Use `After` when you want to create a delay. Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, but this is at the end of the code - which is good practice so that the main thread doesn't exit before everything is finished. In a real example you would have `after.start()`, then all the rest of your code (what ever we want to happen during the 300ms). Then at the end we join all `After` threads. I will edit the answer to clarify.